# issue with tests codepen

Tags: html, css

Okay so I have this course I'm doing and i need to pass these last two tests on my [project](https://codepen.io/mr_dog/pen/xxqjJKW?editors=1100) so i can start the next project but I've tried a variety of things and it still says that it does not meet the standards. I've done 8/10 of the test and the last 2 are in the same area, i thought i did it right but im getting the message saying it isn't correct. Can someone help?

This is the code that has an issue apparently:

```
    <figure id="img-div">
        <img id="image" src="https://img.jamieoliver.com/home/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/salmon630x420.jpg" alt="fishie :>">
        <figcaption id="img-caption">
            hee hoo fune fishie picture
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
```

I thought this was what it needed since it looks like this in the example but it does not look right.

Comment: I don't know what is the issue here?

Comment: neither do i. there should be a little green menu on the top left of the preview and it still says 8/10 and i dont know what the problem is. i would ask on the freecodecamp forum where im taking my course but i cant for some reason.

Comment: I mean I didn't understand your issue here. do you want to open the codepen and click something to check it out?

Comment: i just realized that for non users of freecodecamp the menu doesnt work i think, the menu, when clicked, shows a dropdown menu where you select a test suite and when you run the tests it gives you a score, i will include screen captures. issue for me is that there are 8/10 of them done, but the ones that are for the image do not work even though it says it works.

Comment: it is working , just do what i told you in answer, you have `id="img-div"` in 3 places :)

Comment: It might be because you have several different elements with the same id on one page. The id should be unique for all elements.

Comment: ive made the rest of the id="img-div" all to id="image" but it still doesnt work

Comment: You should not use the same id in multiple places. Instead of `id="img-div"` use `class="img-div"`. Also update in your css from `#img-div` to `.img-div`

Comment: ive tried class="img-div" with no results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you left `id="img-div"` here

```
 <figure id="img-div">
    <img id="image" src="https://img.jamieoliver.com/home/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/salmon630x420.jpg" alt="fishie :>" />
    <figcaption id="img-caption">
        hee hoo fune fishie picture
    </figcaption>
 </figure>
```

and remove `id="img-div"` from other places

Comment: well i did but now the images have no stile and nothing changed. this predicament is skinning me alive

Comment: im sorry, i dont quite understand your comment

Comment: it still says 8/10

Comment: Mate, did you do what i told you in answer ?. only 1  `id="img-div"` needs to stay (last one). When i do that the score is 10/10 :)

Comment: i think i should probably add my new saved version of my codepen on here, as i think it needs to be here so that you can see; everything else has an id of either img, image, or some variation of "salmonphoto", here's the codepen

Comment: When you run the test, click on red button to see where your errors are

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236390/discussion-between-dog-and-nikola-pavicevic).